# QNEAT3 routing with custom length

Tags: qgis, routing

I am trying to create Iso-Areas with the great QGIS package QNEAT3, with the added requirement, that I would like to specify which attribute contains the distance of the segment.

This is required because to estimate if kids can go on their own to school in Switzerland, the difference in elevation is also relevant. The "distance" I would like to use for calculating Iso-Areas equals:

`Segment_length + Elevation_Difference * 10`

I could calculate this "distance" with a DEM and the road slope calculator plugin in QGIS, and now I am trying to generate the Iso-Areas. I have tried to use time optimization instead of distance optimization, but I tend to think that the result is meaningless, since I am not providing a speed as input.

What options do I have for this calculation in QGIS or with another software?

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/418969/88814

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to calculating "distance" by incorporating elevation differences is a thoughtful way to estimate travel difficulty, especially for pedestrian routes. Here are some steps and options you can consider using QGIS and other tools:

**Preprocessing in QGIS:**

If you haven't already, calculate the "effective distance" for each road segment as you described (Segment_length + Elevation_Difference * 10) and store it as an attribute in your road network layer.
Make sure your road network is topologically correct. This is crucial for network analysis.

**Using QNEAT3 Plugin in QGIS:**

While QNEAT3 is primarily designed for isochrones based on time, you can still use it for distance-based isochrones if you treat your "effective distance" as a "time" measure.
In the QNEAT3 settings, choose the attribute that contains your calculated "effective distance". While the plugin may interpret this as time, it will essentially be treating it as a distance measure since that's how you've defined it.

**Using pgRouting with PostGIS:**

If you're comfortable with databases, consider using PostGIS with pgRouting. You can import your road network into a PostGIS database.
Create a new column for your "effective distance" and use pgRouting functions to generate isochrones. pgRouting offers more flexibility and can handle complex network analysis tasks.

**Custom Scripting:**

You can write a Python script using QGIS's PyQGIS framework or a standalone script using libraries like NetworkX or OSMnx. These libraries can handle network analysis and allow you to define custom cost functions (like your "effective distance").

**GIS Software Alternatives:**

If you're open to using other GIS software, GRASS GIS has modules for network analysis that might be adaptable to your needs.

**Validation and Visualization:**

After generating the isochrones, it's important to validate them. Check if the results make sense by comparing them with real-world scenarios.
Visualize the isochrones in QGIS, perhaps using different colors to represent different "distance" ranges.
In summary, while QNEAT3 might not directly support distance-based isochrones with custom attributes, you can repurpose its time-based isochrones feature by treating your "effective distance" as time. Alternatively, explore other tools like pgRouting, custom scripting, or other GIS software if QNEAT3 doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply. Could you edit the formatting, so that the copy-pasted headlines are easier to interpret?